# Dimension of the image equal to dimension of space implies surjectivity in complete varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I do not know much on abelian varities but I am working on Mumford's Abelian Varities and in the second chapter the arose some questions to me. 
Actually, it seems to me as I am lacking of a lot of background here, so please apologize if me question is just foolish.

We are in the following situation:
$X$ is a complete variety and we consider a map $\psi \colon X\times X \to X\times X$ such that $\dim(Image(\psi))=\dim(X\times X)$. Mumford now claims that this implies, as $X\times X$ is complete, that $\psi$ is surjective.

In the context of vector spaces, this is a well-known result for me, but I have no real clue how to show this in this setting.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, I assume you meant $\dim (Image(\psi))=\dim X$, otherwise it makes no sense (except in the trivial case of $\dim X=0$). The basic fact is that a morphism from a complete variety to any variety is proper and in particular closed.

Comment: thanks I was missing a $\times X$ in the definition of $\psi$.